# Solve the differential equation: $y^{(n)} + \frac{n}{1}y^{(n-1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2}y^{(n-2)} + ...+\frac{n}{1}y' + y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$$y^{(n)} + \frac{n}{1}y^{(n-1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2}y^{(n-2)} + ...+\frac{n}{1}y' + y = 0$$

My attempt is to form the characteristic equation which is:

$$r^{(n)} + \frac{n}{1}r^{n-1} + \frac{n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2}r^{n-2} + ...+\frac{n}{1}r + 1 = 0$$
However, I can't seem to find the factoring pattern that would lead me to the values for $r$...

**edit:** as mentioned in the chat this is a binomial:

$$(r+1)^n=0 \rightarrow r = -1$$

The number of times this repeats is $n$ so we must have a solution of the form:

$$y = C_1e^{-x} + C_2xe^{-x} + ...+C_nx^{n-1}e^{-x}$$

Comment: I don't have time to try it now, but try doing it for small $n$, find the pattern in the solution, and show inductively that it is the solution for all $n$. It's not directly solving the ODE, so maybe not as satisfying, but if it works, it works.

Comment: It is $(1+r)^n = 0$, isn't it?

Comment: Hello :) The coefficients are the binomial coefficients. Remember $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}r^k=(r+1)^n$$

Comment: That looks correct. As a check you can also verify that its a solution by explicitly plugging it in. For doing it its useful to note that the ODE can formally be written $(D+1)^n y = 0$ with the operator $D = d/dx$. If we define $y_k = x^k e^{-x}$ then a quick calculation shows that $(D+1) y_k = k y_{k-1}$ which one can use to show that $(D+1)^{n} y_k = 0$ for all $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots,n-1$.